# Send e-mail notificacion ( including attached files ) after user send information with Guest Entries

Tags: emails, plugin-guestentries

I´m using **Guest Entries** to add to db some info filled by users, including some attach files. Everything works great.

But now i have to send an email with all the info and files that user send, i´m already using **Postmaster** plugin to send a notificacion, it works, but it doesn´t send the attached files ( i mean, i don´t know how to do it ).

Is there a way to do this with the plugin or another way?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the [Postmaster plugin](https://github.com/objectivehtml/Postmaster-for-Craft-CMS), which appears abandoned and hasn't been updated since 2016, you could write a [simple plugin](https://pluginfactory.io) that listened to the [afterSaveEntry](https://github.com/craftcms/guest-entries#the-aftersaveentry-event) event.

That plugin could grab any info from the submitted Entry model, including uploads/attachments, and manually compose and send an email out.

You can see an example of how to do that in code in the [Contact Form](https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form/blob/v2/src/Mailer.php#L65-L103) plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brad! I have a look at your explanation and follow the links, but this task it´s quite complex for me to do, i never create a plugin before, don´t know what components i need and where to put the code. I thought it could be easier.